# Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I have an Activity, and in that I have a class.

```
text=new Dynamictext(...);
text.setText("txt");
```

in my DynamicText java I have this code:

```
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text=text;
    new asyncCreateText().execute();
    //this.createText(text);
}

//private Handler handler = new Handler();

private class asyncCreateText extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    }
}
```

I get:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5176): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

How can I handle this error?

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at com.l.start.DynamicText.setText(DynamicText.java:125)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at com.l.start.OpenGLRenderer.initfonts(OpenGLRenderer.java:168)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at com.l.start.OpenGLRenderer.init(OpenGLRenderer.java:119)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at com.l.start.OpenGLRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(OpenGLRenderer.java:90)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1120)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:975)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5370):     ... 6 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? You seem to be calling some UI method from the background thread or something.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16886486/1919641) will explain the issue in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory... `doInBackground()` runs on a background thread which, since it is not intended to loop, is not connected to a `Looper`.

You most likely don't want to directly instantiate a Handler at all... whatever data your `doInBackground()` implementation returns will be passed to `onPostExecute()` which runs on the UI thread.

```
   mActivity = ThisActivity.this; 

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     new asyncCreateText().execute();
     }
   });
```

**ADDED FOLLOWING THE STACKTRACE APPEARING IN QUESTION:**

Looks like you're trying to start an `AsyncTask` from a GL rendering thread... don't do that cos they won't ever `Looper.loop()` either. AsyncTasks are really designed to be run from the UI thread only.

The least disruptive fix would probably be to call `Activity.runOnUiThread()` with a `Runnable` that kicks off your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: The answer is totally correct. However, in my case, I just had to remove some Toasts (attempting run on the UI thread) from my custom FtpUpload AsyncTask class and voila.

Comment: same error is coming to me i am confuse how to resolve it i read description but am not getting how  to do it can anyone give me code snippest please

Comment: I would upvote this answer except for "The error is self-explanatory"

Answer (score 32):

All the answers above are correct, but I think this is the easiest example possible:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler handler;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    public void clickAButton(View view) {
        // Do something that takes a while
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.setProgress("anything"); // Update the UI
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
}
```

What this does is update a progress bar in the UI thread from a completely different thread passed through the post() method of the handler declared in the activity.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 23):

You create handler in background thread this way

```
private void createHandler() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
          public void run() {
               Looper.prepare();

               final Handler handler = new Handler();
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // Do Work
                        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                   }
                }, 2000);

                Looper.loop();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Not only solves the problem, but also very explanatory. Alittle problem dough. How the structure will change if want it `removeCallbacks` and `quit` when `Work` is done, but not delay is reached. Because work may last longer that predefined delay.

Answer (score 12):

`Activity.runOnUiThread()` does not work for me. I worked around this issue by creating a regular thread this way:

```
public class PullTasksThread extends Thread {
   public void run () {
      Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Thread run...");
   }
}
```

and calling it from the GL update this way:

```
new PullTasksThread().start();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me calling it from GL but you've to be sure you are not calling Toasts on run method!! AsyncTask didn't worked calling it from GL.

Thanks!

Comment: Works great for me in replacing an AsyncTask.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try running you asyntask from the UI thread. I faced this issue when I wasn't doing the same!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
 //your code here that talks with the UI level widgets/ try to access the UI 
//elements from this block because this piece of snippet will run in the UI/MainThread.                                     
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Try to add little explanation. Code only answers are not very appreciated on SO.

Answer (score 0):

For all the ***Kotlin*** lovers, here is the code for you

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
      // any UI update here
}
```