# Recommended resources for understanding concepts in Android

Tags: android, internals

After a relatively easy coast to simple app coding, I would like to **understand** better the intricate relationships between various **conceptual components** in Android.

More specifically, I would like to understand what is [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html), [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

As you may noticed, the above 3 terms are links to formal documentation in http://developer.android.com so my question may seem strange, so let me explain: That documentation may be perfect for someone who already understands how things work in Android, but I need something that sequentially walks through fundamentals, building on top of previous concepts.

To summarize, I need some sort of tutorial on core *inner* building blocks of Android. Can you recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) is probably your best resource for threading on Android.

The moral of the story is that `AsyncTask` makes multithreading easier for you.

Comment: OMG you are an angel. There's so much documentation that I can't find the important stuff... I found http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html but it's not as dummy-friendly as Painless Threading. :)

Comment: There are some really nice articles in there. If you click around on the left pane you can find more as well!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare/5009894#5009894 suggests that AsyncTask can't be started from a non-UI thread. Instead, he suggests yet another level of indirection by calling Activity.runOnUiThread() with a Runnable that kicks off your AsyncTask. Whew...

Answer (score 1):

Runnable is a core Java interface - it represents a code part that can be run (usually by a specific thread).

Handler is an Android class that is responsible for posting a Runnable\Message so that a particular thread will run or process them (in a specific order).

Looper is the structure that holds the Runnable\Message queue that a HandlerThread will read from.