# aSyncTask created from a Handler

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here's what I'm trying to do first.  I'm trying to launch a MapView, which grabs the user's location and loads an overlay with data that changes based upon the user's location.

Code overview:
I have a MapView that grabs the current user's location on creation.
The locationOverlay I'm using calls out a Runnable on first fix:

```
locationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(centerAroundFix);
```

This Runnable, centerAroundFix, starts an aSyncTask.  As soon as I call the 'new aSyncTask', this error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

The asynctask's job is to fetch data, create the overlay, and add the overlay.  Creating and executing the asynctask works fine outside of the Runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I didn't see this already...

[Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Edit: works.  Here's my code.  Wrapped the updateLocation() call with "mHandler.post":

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private Runnable centerAroundFix = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Jump to current location and set zoom accordingly */
        map.getController().animateTo(locationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        map.getController().setZoom(12);
        /* This is a different thread.  I need to call this from a thread that has a 'Looper' prepared. */
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                updateLocation();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Handler in the UIThread. For example as class member:

```
public class Activity extends Activity{
    private Handler handler = new Handler();        
}
```