# Remove extra from intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using Parse push notifications and have these methods to alert the user with what the message was. How would I show the AlertDialog once and after that remove that data from the intent so that in case the app simply is paused rather than killed it doesn't pop up again?

At the end of onCreate()

```
handlePushIntent(getIntent());
```

I overrode onNewIntent()

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handlePushIntent(intent);
}
```

and my method:

```
 private void handlePushIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras == null || extras.isEmpty())
        return;
    if (extras.containsKey("com.parse.Data")) {
        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(extras.get("com.parse.Data")
                    .toString());
            String alert = data.getString("alert");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(alert);
            builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("VNL", "Push Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you form this into a question?

Comment: There you go. Changed it.

Comment: What do you mean with "the app is simply paused rather than killed"? Does that include orientation changes too (which would kill the activity and recreate it)?

Comment: Yes orientation changes too. This means the app isn't completely killed like if the user hits the home button and opens other apps. I managed to solve it by storing the parse push hash in shared preferences and checking if the current push data is equal to what is in the shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the fact that the intent object automatically gets added to the back-stack by the framework is contributing to your 'state' issues around pause/resume...

There are other scenarios for using a the message loop and a handler where you can show something on the screen ( alert / progressmessage ) by using the handler/message loop and consuming the message once WITHOUT pushing and object ( like intent ) to the back/stack.

'easiest example possible' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare) shows inline handler/runnable where you can put your alert without the back/stack

Answer (score 0):

I use another approach. For showing the push notification I use an EventBus and post the Notification on the EventBus as a sticky event. As soon as I display the message I remove the event from the EventBus.

See http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/ for more details about StickyEvents.