# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 callbacks within OpenGL thread

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, opengl-es-2.0

I was wondering if there is a way to receive callbacks inside the OpenGL thread (meaning **NO** inter-thread communication).
I've tried to use the `Handler`, but I it didn't work, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare).
Also:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I have some custom Animations in OpenGL which can be initialized. Now I want to receive some sort of callback after the animation is finished. The `AsyncTask` would not be the best choice for my purpose, since I am not able to call `return` properly in my scenario. The `Handler` would have been a good choice - each element would have had a reference to the `Handler` and simply send some message with valuable information when the animation is finished.

Is there another way to receive callbacks within the OpenGL thread?

Comment: Should _GLSurfaceView.queueEvent(Runnable)_ be close enough ; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#queueEvent(java.lang.Runnable) ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm already using queueEvent to access the GL thread from outside, but how can I achieve callbacks within the GL thread?

Comment: So, the case is you want to send notification from GLSurfaceView.Renderer methods back to UI thread?

Comment: No, I have a coordinator inside the GL Renderer which should invoke another animation after a previous animation has finished. That should happen automatically, no need to handle anything in the UI thread - it should work in the GL thread exclusively.

Comment: And is there a reason why you cannot implement an interface to handle these events in your Renderer, which could be passed to each element?

Comment: Sounds like a neat idea, I'll take a look into that!