# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside Handler()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am calling a Handler class from a background thread. In the Handler class, I am trying to display a toast. Theoratically it should work flawlessly because Handler is the Queue that forwards the UI tasks to the main UI thread. However, in my case the I am getting exception.

```
private void firstTimeLogin() {

        final LoginUiThreadHandler loginHandler = new LoginUiThreadHandler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message m = loginHandler.obtainMessage();

                Bundle bund = new Bundle();
                bund.putInt("loginResult", 1);
                m.setData(bund);

                loginHandler.handleMessage(m);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private class LoginUiThreadHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            int loginResult = msg.getData().getInt("loginResult");
            if(loginResult == 0) 
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5009894/1320616

Comment: final LoginUiThreadHandler loginHandler = new LoginUiThreadHandler(getMainLooper()).

Comment: if you want to send a `Message` call `sendMessage(m)`, not `handleMessage(m)`, also dont use `setData` for just one int, see all `obtainMessage` methods

Answer (score -1):

Replace with -

`LoginUiThreadHandler loginHandler = new LoginUiThreadHandler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

instead of-

`LoginUiThreadHandler loginHandler = new LoginUiThreadHandler();`

Comment: Then, you need to create constructor in LoginUIThreadHanlder with parameter Looper and pass to super(looper) as-

LoginUiThreadHandler(Looper l){
        super(l);
    }